# How to exlude from split text whithin bracket - jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

**Hi, I have an issue and trying to split a string to be an array.**


**My current code:**

```
var str = 'code:(112 114) word:testing tags:(english math)';
var arr = str.split(' ');
console.log(arr);
```

**Result :**

```
[
  "code:(112",
  "114)",
  "word:testing",
  "tags:(english",
  "math)"
]
```

**But I want result be like this**

```
[
  "code:(112 114)",
  "word:testing",
  "tags:(english math)"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex` to do it

```js
var str = 'code:(112 114) word:testing tags:(english math)';
var arr = str.split(/\s(?=\w+:)/);
arr.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

Output:

```
code:(112 114)
word:testing
tags:(english math)
```

Note:`s(?=\w+:)` means find space with characters and **:** after it,but only find the space,so that it can split the string as you want.
In your case it will ignore space between `112 114` and `english math`,but it will find space between `) word` and `testing tags`